# How to make extra functionality on output values?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to access results of dice form "Attacker" and "Defender" and compare them. Have no idea how to do it. I've already tried IF loop (`if a > b,   print "lala"`) but it doesn't work.

```
import random
counter = 0
while counter < 1:
    a = random.randrange(1,6)
    b = random.randrange(1,6)
    c = random.randrange(1,6)
    print("Attacker:")
    print(a,"-", b,"-", c)
    counter += 1
counter = 0
while counter < 1:
    d = random.randrange(1,6)
    e = random.randrange(1,6)
    g = random.randrange(1,6)
    print("Defender:")
    print(d,"-", e,"-", g)
    counter += 1
```

Expected program is printing 3 random numbers in range(0-6) for each player and then compare results prining "Player1 (orP2) Wins"

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `a`-`g` variables outside their `while` loops. The scope of variables determines where you can use them. You've declared those variables within a `while` loop, so you can only use them within their `while` loop.

```py
a = None  # or whatever default value
b = None
...
g = None

counter = 0
while counter < 1:
    a = random.randrange(1, 6)
    ...

counter = 0
while counter < 1:
    d = random.randrange(1, 6)
    ...

if a > b:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
counter = 0
number_of_dice=3
playerA = [0]*number_of_dice
playerB = [0]*number_of_dice

#let's fill those arrays
for i in range(number_of_dice):
    playerA[i] = random.randrange(1,6)
    playerB[i] = random.randrange(1,6)

print("Player A threw ",playerA)
print("Player B threw ",playerB)

#now evaluate the scores
wins_for_A = 0
wins_for_B = 0
for i in range(number_of_dice):
    if playerA[i]>playerB[i]:
        wins_for_A+=1
    elif playerA[i]<playerB[i]:
        wins_for_B+=1
    #no else... that means a draw

if wins_for_A>wins_for_B:
    print("player A wins")
elif wins_for_A<wins_for_B:
    print("player B wins")
else:
    print("draw")
```

it outputs something like

```
Player A threw  [5, 3, 3]
Player B threw  [3, 2, 3]
player A wins

Process finished with exit code 0
```